# Gauntlet that provides benefits of Monkey Grip?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, content-identification

I remember reading about gauntlets that had an effect what somewhat like Monkey Grip (*Complete Warrior* feat). The thing was that the wording was off just a bit. How I read it, and my DM agreed, was that you could use this with the Monkey Grip feat, and you player would be able to wield a weapon as though it was two sizes larger.

I think it was in the *Magic Item Compendium*. What are the gauntlets called? I loved them, but now I cannot find them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Strongarm bracers*, *Magic Item Compendium* pg. 139. It’s 6,000 gp to wield a weapon as if you were a size larger without penalties.

In most cases, that’s an average of +1 damage, which not amazing, but if you’re stacking size bonuses it can be worth more than that. Certainly, in all ways, better than the terrible Monkey Grip feat. You should never take Monkey Grip, since a feat is worth quite a bit more than 6,000 gp (and **way** more than +1 damage), and because with Monkey Grip you *still* take penalties, it just lessens them.

As for whether or not they stack, strictly speaking they would not. Both say that they allow you to wield a weapon one size category larger “*than you are*,” not “than you otherwise could.” Since neither actually changes your size, if you are say Medium, *strongarm bracers* allows you to wield Large weapons with no penalty, or Monkey Grip allows you to wield Large weapons with a −2 penalty, but they don’t interact or stack.

Seeing as *strongarm bracers* explicitly do not stack with powerful build (racial trait of half-giants and goliaths that allow them to behave in some ways, including for the wielding of weapons, as if they were a size category larger), it seems likely that the authors of *Magic Item Compendium* intended that the *strongarm bracers* could not be used to wield weapons more than one size category larger than yourself.

Comment: Could this answer also address the possibility of wielding an oversized shield as mentioned in [this (now-deleted) answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101199/8610)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Improved Shield Bash deals more damage *as if* the shield were larger, but doesn’t actually increase the size of the shield. Kind of a corner case. The DM’s ruling in that case that the larger shield grants more AC is, I believe, either mistaken or a houserule.

Comment: O, *that* part's *totally* a house rule. I'm more concerned about the idea that the *bracers* may allow a Medium creature to employ effectively (rather than as, for instance, a sled) any kind of Large shield *at all*, a shield being armor and the shield bash being the weapon. That kind of thing.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, I see. Seems to me you could argue that you can use the Large shield as a weapon just fine, but are unable to actually use it as a shield. That would seem the most consistent? Though really I’m not particularly concerned by Medium characters using Large shields, honestly. Either way, *probably* better as a separate question, I think.

Comment: I'm a *little* bothered by it since that would make the *bracers*' effect—being able to use effectively a shield sized for a creature bigger than the wielder—unique (so far as I'm aware) in the entire *D&D 3.5e* corpus (Large shields, for instance, being typically vendor trash *no matter their special abilities!*). I would, however, argue much the same as you put forth: a wielder could use the shield *as a weapon* but couldn't benefit from it *as a shield.* In sum, *fair enough.* I guess we'll wait and see if it gets asked separately.